# Using forbidden column names in doctrine 1.2

Tags: php, doctrine

I'm using postgresql database.
I have table with column called "from" (I can't change it).
Sql insertion query generated by doctrine are incorrect, because column name "from" should be closed by quotation marks. How can I tell doctrine to do this?

I believe, there is fast and clean way to correct that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you change it? Anyways, smack the guy who built THAT PoS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `$conn->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_QUOTE_IDENTIFIER, true);`? From [Docs -> Configuration -> Identifier quoting](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/hu/configuration#identifier-quoting)